# Upload a blob with Phonegap FileTransfer - and receive binary

Tags: cordova, binary, base64, file-transfer

I want to upload some binary data (e.g. image, or zip) to a server using phonegap, and receive binary as the response. Is it possible?
While the upload works very well with the `FileTransfer` and a file stored on the disk, I cant get it to work with a blob

```
var blob = new Blob([something], {type: 'application/zip'});
var blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(blobURL, encodeURI('http://server'), win, fail, options);
```

the blobURL of course is something like

```
blob:1234-...
```

which FileTransfer does not find. I tried to save the blob first, passing its path to `FileTransfer` - but Phonegaps `FileWriter` cannot process a `blob`.

Using `xhr` is not an option as you cannot receive binary files with it in Phonegap (WP8). The `Mimetypeoverride` Trick does not work in this case as Internet Explorers xhr does not have this option.

I am working with Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send binary data through Phonegap file Transfer.

Your binary data must be converted to **BASE64** string and then transferred to server. Same thing goes for the other way.

Here's a tutorial how to handle binary data transfer with Phonegap: http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/03/01/phonegap-tip-binary-filesystem-data/